# Which Microsoft + Client Technology should an ASP.NET WEBFORM experienced developer move to?

Tags: asp.net, angular, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

For years I've been working on ASP.NET WebForms and 3rd party controls such as DevExpress or Telerik, also did some MVC (basic stuff) and some big AngularJS projects with .NET APIs in the back.

Now I have the task to build a new admin system (lots of complicated CRUDs, listings, reports, dashboards) and I wish to take the right path here in order to avoid having to rewrite this in the coming years.

Should I go with:

- ASP.NET CORE MVC + some telerik component to help?
- ASP.NET CORE MVC + React (no React knowledge)
- ASP.NET CORE APIs + Angular ( I read it's "losing" against React and should not go this way)

I guess sticking with WebForms is not an option. I'm willing to learn so anything you can help me with will be of great help.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stackoverflow, you can try posting it on: [softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: BTW, **Stackoverflow Trends** is quite a good tool for choosing a technology, for example [angular vs. reactjs](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=angular%2Creactjs)

Comment: Take a look at blazor